# The current TransactionScope is already complete error after converting to .net core 3.1

Tags: transactions, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

After an update to 3.1, we've been receiving error messages that state:

System.InvalidOperationException: The current TransactionScope is already complete.

The only real change we've made to this process is to move from the 2.x way of doing using statements with brackets to the 3.x way of using statements without brackets (as is recommended).  Are we doing something wrong?

Current Way:

```
// As multiple copies of this service can be running at once, we should lock the table while we flag the messages to be worked on
using var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
              new TransactionOptions() 
              { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted });
messagesToProcess = context.InboundMessageQueueRecords.Where(x => x.State == QueueMessageState.New)
          .OrderBy(x => x.Added)
          .Take(NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_TO_PROCESS).ToList();
// Flag them as in progress
messagesToProcess.ForEach(x => x.State = QueueMessageState.InProgress);
context.SaveChanges();
transactionScope.Complete();
```

Old Way:

```
// As multiple copies of this service can be running at once, we should lock the table while we flag the messages to be worked on
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
              new TransactionOptions() 
              { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
{
  messagesToProcess = context.InboundMessageQueueRecords.Where(x => x.State == QueueMessageState.New)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Added)
            .Take(NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_TO_PROCESS).ToList();
  // Flag them as in progress
  messagesToProcess.ForEach(x => x.State = QueueMessageState.InProgress);
  context.SaveChanges();
  transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the end of the using block, it probably completes the scope. So I would try removing the `transactionScope.Complete();` from the old way and check if it's completed.